# Difference between consecutive rows but different column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to find the difference between two consecutive rows but different column. I have written a query as follows

```
select ticketid,createddate,expirydate ,TIMESTAMP_DIFF(
    timestamp_seconds(expirytimestamp),
    timestamp_seconds(
      lag(createdtimestamp) over (partition by ticketid order by ticketid)
    ),
    Minute
  ) AS result from table
```

Expected result

```
TicketID    createdtimestamp    Expirytimestamp created date    Expirydate  Expected result in minutes
121 1574170201  1574328843  2019-12-01 1:25:05  2019-12-01 7:24:53  NULL
121 1574170202  1574372109  2019-12-01 2:55:02  2019-12-01 8:54:50  300
121 1574256733  1574415375  2019-12-01 4:24:59  2019-12-01 10:24:47 240
121 1574285577  1574458641  2019-12-01 5:54:56  2019-12-01 11:54:44 300
121 1574328843  1574501907  2019-12-01 7:24:53  2019-12-01 13:24:41 240
121 1574372109  1574545173  2019-12-01 8:54:50  2019-12-01 14:54:38 300
121 1574415375  1574588439  2019-12-01 10:24:47 2019-12-01 16:24:35 240
```

Could any one suggest. It's not giving the desired result.
Data Not found this Query

Here is the actual result I got

```
TicketID    createdtimestamp    Expirytimestamp created date    Expirydate  Expected result in minutes
121 1574170200  1574170680  2019-11-19 13:30:00 2019-11-19 13:38:00 null
121 1574170201  1574173801  2019-11-19 13:30:01 2019-11-19 14:30:01 60
121 1574170201  1574173801  2019-11-19 13:30:01 2019-11-19 14:30:01 60
121 1574170201  1574173801  2019-11-19 13:30:01 2019-11-19 14:30:01 60
121 1574170202  1574170512  2019-11-19 13:30:02 2019-11-19 13:35:12 5
121 1574170202  1574170512  2019-11-19 13:30:02 2019-11-19 13:35:12 5
121 1574170202  1574170902  2019-11-19 13:30:02 2019-11-19 13:41:42 11
121 1574256733  1574257433  2019-11-20 13:32:13 2019-11-20 13:43:53 1453
121 1574343249  1574343949  2019-11-21 13:34:09 2019-11-21 13:45:49 1453
121 1574429680  1574430380  2019-11-22 13:34:40 2019-11-22 13:46:20 1452
121 1574516458  1574517158  2019-11-23 13:40:58 2019-11-23 13:52:38 1457
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, current and expected results, all as tabular text.

Comment: Matching sample table data is also needed.

Comment: I don't see the column resulted from TIMESTAMP_DIFF() function in your output, is the problem within this function? I can see that Expirydate is different for these two tables, but It comes from the select, right?

Comment: Yes, Alexandre M

Comment: Can you provide sample data? So I can reproduce the case. Also, why is the _Expiredate_ different in your output?

Comment: @ Alexandre Moraes ,One is expected one is actual. Basically I need to know how i can subtract  between different column consecutive row

Comment: @syncdm2012, which one would be the source table? Also, when using _TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP, date_part)_ you do not need to transform each time stamp to seconds, since you already specify it with the date_part string, [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#timestamp_diff).

Answer (score 1):

This is putting things in an arbitrary order:

```
lag(createdtimestamp) over (partition by ticketid order by ticketid)
```

I think you want:

```
lag(createdtimestamp) over (partition by ticketid order by createdtimestamp)
```

Note the difference in the `order by`.